# How to loop a statement in linux

Tags: linux, unix, for-loop, terminal

I'm trying to loop a statement/output in linux. So in my ssh directory if I do ls. There is a file call hello.c which prints Hello James. What i'm trying to do is a for loop that prints it 4 times.

This is what i've tried.

```
for((int i=1;i<=4;i++));
do
./hello.c
echo $i
done
```

However nothing is printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash as a programming language, is dynamically typed, so there are no type declarations. So you can remove the type declaration from the line bellow:

```
for((int i=1;i<=4;i++));
     ^^^
```

i.e. change it to

```
for((i=1;i<=4;i++));
```

Additionally, are you sure that you can call the program by saying `./hello.c`? This is usually the source file and is not executable.

Comment: Your right I can't call that. There are 3 files in my directory. One of them is a.out,hello and hello.c.

Comment: ./hello.c doesn't call the output but ./hello does call the output hello James

Answer (score 0):

Using the shell command line you type (in the shell prompt)

```
for((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do echo "hello"; done
# outputs "hello" four times
```

Whatever you need to create a script, you should edit a file:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > my_script.sh
echo 'for((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do echo "hello"; done' >> my_script.sh
```

and then change the permissions to make it executable.

```
chmod +x my_script.sh
./my_script.sh
```

Make sure to read one of the many tutorials about shell (bash) programming,
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html is a good one.